# React : Toggling PopUp re-renders entire component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Im still figuring the ins and outs of React so please bear with me here.

Im making a component using MaterialUI and that component contains a grid and a PopOver.
A crude mockup could look like this:

```
export const Overblik = () => {
    const [filterAnchorEl, setFilterAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

    return (
      <div>
      <IconButton onClick={handleFilterClick}></IconButton>
          <Popover
            anchorEl={filterAnchorEl}
            open={Boolean(filterAnchorEl)}
            onClose={handleFilterClose}
            anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'left'
          }}><div>stuff</div></Popover>
          <Grid>[somelongListGoesHere]</Grid>
        </div>
        );
      }
```

Now the thing is that when I toggle the filterAnchorEl state to show the popover, the grid marked with `[somelongListGoesHere]` also re-renders, making the popover seem sluggish.
I figure there must be something wrong with my approach, but any suggestions on how to better handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to move the grid to another component

```
const MyGrid = () => (<Grid>[somelongListGoesHere]</Grid>)
```

and then in your component just render it

```
 <IconButton onClick={handleFilterClick}></IconButton>
 <Popover ... />
 <MyGrid />
```

if no props change for `MyGrid` component it won't re-render.
you can also use `React.memo` to cache it like this:

```
const MyGrid = React.memo(() => (<Grid>[somelongListGoesHere]</Grid>))
```